# Discrete math: Logical equivalence using limited connectives

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

So this time I'm trying find the equivalent forms of some simple propositions, but I can only make the equivalent formulas using $\to$ and $\bot$ as the only connectives. One is $p \lor q$ and the other's $p \leftrightarrow q$. I've been trying to figure this out for hours but nothing's coming up.

Comment: I am somewhat confused by what you are trying to do. Are you just trying to find equivalent forms of propositions or are you trying to do so using only certain symbols?

Comment: Trying to find equivalent forms using just the two symbols specified.

Comment: $\lnot p$ must be defined as $p \to \bot$.

Comment: $p \lor q$ must be defined as $\lnot p \to q$ i.e. as $(p \to \bot) \to q$.

Comment: $p↔q$  must be defined as $(p→q)∧(q→p)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lnot p$ must be defined as:

> $p \to \bot$.

$p∨q$ must be defined as $¬p→q$, i.e. as $(p→⊥)→q$.

$p∧q$ must be defined as $¬(p→¬q)$, i.e. as $(p→(q \to \bot)) \to \bot$.

$p↔q$ must be defined as $(p→q)∧(q→p)$, i.e. as:

> $((p→q)→((q→p) \to \bot)) \to \bot$.

Comment: Thank you. I kept trying the find a small propositional statement to solve these  because I was using a truth table.